# Python: load words from file into a set

Tags: python, text-files

I have a simple text file with several thousands of words, each in its own line, e.g.

```
aardvark
hello
piper
```

I use the following code to load the words into a set (I need the list of words to test membership, so set is the data structure I chose):

```
my_set = set(open('filename.txt'))
```

The above code produces a set with the following entries (each word is followed by a space and new-line character:

```
("aardvark \n", "hello \n", "piper \n")
```

What's the simplest way to load the file into a set but get rid of the space and \n?

Thanks

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The strip() method of strings removes whitespace from both ends.

```
set(line.strip() for line in open('filename.txt'))
```

Comment: This is superior to the set solution if you have a large file, because map will load the entire file into memory as a list of lines, which will then be discarded (itertools.imap can fix that, though).

Comment: @Ryan: that is true for Python <= 2.6, but in 3.0 map returns a generator.

Comment: @RyanGinstrom Sorry for being so late, but I could not help asking this question to you! I had observed that `print` `my_set[0]` would still print `aardvark`. Did it move the cursor to the next line after printing ?Please correct me if I am mistaken, but how does this happen ? (Python 27) Thanks !

Comment: @Noob yes, `print` adds a newline. Try `print repr(my_set[0])`.

Comment: Does it close the file handler as well?

Answer (score 16):

Just load all file data and split it, it will take care of one word per line or multiple words per line separated by spaces, also it will be faster to load whole file at once unless your file is in GBs

```
words =  set(open('filename.txt').read().split())
```

Comment: So this would work if I have one word per line and also if I have multiple words per line? (assuming if I have a line like "hello bye" I want "hello" and "bye" to be two separate words in the set)

Comment: yes it will basically split on space, new line tabs etc
so you can have all words in single line
or in multiple line or mixed

Comment: and don't worry abt loading whole file in memory unless you have very very big file which I doubt
few MBs is perfect and this will be fastest

Answer (score 4):

```
my_set = set(map(str.strip, open('filename.txt')))
```

Comment: This solution will properly remove any spaces and newline characters by applying the str.strip method to each line of filename.txt

Answer (score 2):

To remove only the right hand spaces.

```
set(map(str.rstrip, open('filename.txt')))
```

Comment: If the file size was fairly large this method would be potentially faster. It avoids an extra comparison with isspace() to the left side of each string.

Comment: Yes, the author only specified spaces on the right hand side, so it made sense to do rstrip instead of strip or split.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("filename.txt") as f:
    mySet = map(str.rstrip, f)
```

If you want to use this in Python 2.5, you need

```
from __future__ import with_statement
```

Comment: I think that here you have syntax error:
    set(map(str.rstrip('\n') str, f)

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("filename.txt") as f:
    s = set([line.rstrip('\n') for line in f])
```

Comment: you don't need list comprehension there