# Load c++ memory file into Python

Tags: c++, python

I have a file that in C++ I load into array using below code:

```
int SomeTable[10000];

int LoadTable()
{
    memset(SomeTable, 0, sizeof(SomeTable));
    FILE * fin = fopen("SomeFile.dar", "rb");
    size_t bytesread = fread(SomeTable, sizeof(SomeTable), 1, fin);
    fclose(fin);
}
```

The file is binary code of 10000 integers, so in C++ it could be directly loaded into memory. Is there a fansy way of doing that in Python?

best regards,
Rok

Comment: How to read from files. http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874017/python-load-words-from-file-into-a-set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write an array into a file using a short C code:

```
int main ()
{
  FILE * pFile;
  int a[3] = {1,2,3};
  pFile = fopen ( "file.bin" , "wb" );
  fwrite (a , 1 , sizeof(a) , pFile );
  fclose (pFile);
  return 0;
}
```

The binary file can be loaded directly into a [python array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html)

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import array
>>> a=array.array('l') # 'l' is the type code for signed integer
>>> file=open('file.bin','rb')
>>> a.read(file,3)
>>> print a
array('l', [1, 2, 3])
>>> print a[0]
1
```